# How to use the idiom "long face"

Tags: idioms

Suppose someone has gone out to do something and when he comes back you see he is very unhappy because he has not succeeded in doing the job in his question. Could someone please let me know which one of the following sentences and the ways I've used the idiom "long face" sounds more natural:

> - He came back with a long face.
> - He came back with his a face long.
> - He came back face long.
> - He came back long faced.

Comment: If you use google to look up _"long face" idiom_, you quickly find [this definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/long-face), with the example _He's been walking around with a long face ever since he failed the examination_. Clearly this uses the expression in the same way as your first sentence. Your second option is not grammatical (what's the article doing there?) The others seem to be tries at being original. Why do you think usage as in a dictionary example would _not_ be a good way to use the idiom?

Comment: The first version is probably idiomatically more common than the last. The middle two aren't grammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The third can be salvaged with a comma after *back*.

Comment: @Lawrence: Okay - that one's not strictly "ungrammatical". But it would be *extremely* unlikely without a determiner: [*...came back, **his** face long*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22came+back+his+face+long%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's like "Stand straight, chin up". Completely idiomatic, though I'd defer to the linguists on its formal grammar.

Comment: @Lawrence: It's not *quite* like "chin up". The imperative *Face long!* doesn't really seem credible as a way of telling your paid mourners to look more solemn, for example. On the other side of the deal, what optimist has ever approached his problems ***up-chinned**?* But at this level, the concept of "grammatical" doesn't really apply. What we're talking about is what's ***idiomatic***.

Comment: @oerkelens thank you for bringing up this matter. As far as I know there is no rule in English language. It's just guidance. some guidance look like rule. they probably isn't. What I ask here is based on American contemporary and natural English. When a foreigner talks, you natives would understand immediately their meanings. But how to speak naturally is what I'm going to know about each sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The term "long face" is used as a noun phrase.

> **A long face**
>   If you have a long face, you look sad:
>   *"Why do you have such a long face?" "My boyfriend doesn't want to see me any more."*
>   [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-long-face)

Of your four alternatives, the first is idiomatic:

> - He came back with a long face.

Answer (score -2):

"Long face" means "to be sad", "to be afraid" or "to be tired".

Here are some examples:

- He has a long face (He is sad)
- He was studying and he had a long face (He was sad because he was studying)
- When He loses He has a long face. (when He loses He is sad)

Comment: _When He lose has a long face_ is not grammatical. There is an unneeded capital, _lose_ is conjugated incorrectly, and _has_ is missing a subject.

Comment: Is it right now?

Comment: Unless you mean God, _he_ is not spelled with a capital...